# Automatic login with Curl, being one of the input fields

Tags: php, html, curl, dom

I am trying to automatically log in with Curl on this site: https://online.hinode.com.br, and the consultant ID must be filled in automatically, along with the status that will always be the same, after login should be redirected to a specific product page. However, the codes I tested did not go anywhere! No error, html does not load ... I think it should be this select field, I do not know.

Code:

```
<?php
// Start cURL
$ch = curl_init();
// Define the original URL (of the login form)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://online.hinode.com.br/');
// Enable POST protocol
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Define the parameters that will be sent (user and password for example)
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'loja_consultor=fulano&estado=SP');
// Imitate the boss behavior of browsers: handle cookies
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
// Set the transfer type (Padrão: 1)
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Execute the requisition
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
// Define a new URL to be called (after login)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://online.hinode.com.br/detalhes.asp?IdProduto=769&ssp=830852727SSP20171218HP115020');
// Execute the second request
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
```

// Close cURL
    curl_close ($ch);

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikaf1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmDBs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4678.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXZD4.png)

Comment: Downvoting due to not being in english.

Comment: Questions on the main Stack Overflow site must be in English, try [pt.so].

Comment: I translated, sorry, it's the first time I'm looking for help here on Stack :)

Comment: you can add $ee = curl_getinfo($ch);print_r($ee);print_r($store); to get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: @tbedner                                                                                                Warning: curl_getinfo(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/redirect.php on line 24
123456.                                                         https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikaf1.png

Comment: if you remove the curl_getinfo($ch) part (and its echo), what happens then?

Comment: @tbedner  If I remove $ee = curl_getinfo($ch);print_r($ee);print_r($store) nothing happens turns everything white.

Comment: Leave the print_r($store); in there. I tried my solution below and it was telling me the object was moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
<?php
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$login_url = "https://online.hinode.com.br/loja_valida.asp";
$target_url="https://online.hinode.com.br/detalhes.asp?IdProduto=1294&ssp=1044632862SSP20171218HP180256";
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$field['loja_consultor'] = '228621';
$field['estado'] = 'SP';
$field['acessar'] = 'Acessar';

$datafield = http_build_query($field);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datafield);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
$ket_qua = curl_exec($ch);

echo $ket_qua;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Tks, but when I try this, this happens from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmDBs.png

Comment: If you go to the site and login normally, does it behave as you expect?

Comment: Your image shows you get a 302 redirct to the index page.

Comment: When I go to the site and I get it, he behaves normally. But when I run the php file, nothing is populated.

Comment: I put the link that was directed and nothing happened.

Comment: So it appears the curl is working correctly, and there is an issue with the site itself.Once that is resolved, the curl should work as well. If it doesn't, let me know and we can work on it.

Comment: The site is working properly, so the curl should also, I do not know what is happening

Comment: OK, if you go to the site itself at https://online.hinode.com.br/detalhes.asp?IdProduto=769&ssp=830852727SSP20171218HP115020, you are then presented with a login screen. You type in the consultant ID and the state, hit the submit button and then what happens?

Comment: I'm redirected to the normal page:https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4678.png

Comment: Are those the correct credentials (fulano and SP)? I am redirected back to the login page with them?

Comment: To clarify, I do not need the correct credentials, but I want to make sure the correct ones were put in the curl request to rule that issue out.

Comment: The correct credentials are: $field['loja_consultor'] = '228621';
$field['estado'] = 'SP';    ('estado'  is a field type select)

Comment: the form is posting to loja_valida.asp so it might help to look at that file and see if we are missing anything it expects us to post. I am still getting a 302 redirect to the index page.

Comment: I've put up another code, but it's giving "moved object". I do not know what's going on.